# unclear how to add extra productions to bison grammar to create error messages

Tags: parsing, bison, yacc

This is not homework, but it is from a book.

I'm given a following `bison` spec file:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int yylex();
int yyerror();
%}

%token NUMBER

%%

command : exp { printf("%d\n", $1); }
        ; /* allows printing of the result */

exp : exp '+' term { $$ = $1 + $3; }
    | exp '-' term { $$ = $1 - $3; }
    | term { $$ = $1; }
    ;

term : term '*' factor { $$ = $1 * $3; }
     | factor { $$ = $1; }
     ;

factor : NUMBER { $$ = $1; }
       | '(' exp ')' { $$ = $2; }
       ;

%%

int main() {
  return yyparse();
}

int yylex() {
  int c;

  /* eliminate blanks*/
  while((c = getchar()) == ' ');

  if (isdigit(c)) {
    ungetc(c, stdin);
    scanf("%d", &yylval);
    return (NUMBER);
  }

  /* makes the parse stop */
  if (c == '\n') return 0;

  return (c);
}

int yyerror(char * s) {
  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
  return 0;
} /* allows for printing of an error message */
```

The task is to do the following:

> Rewrite the spec to add the following useful error messages: 
>   
> "missing right parenthesis," generated by the string **(2+3** 
>   
> "missing left parenthesis," generated by the string **2+3)** 
>   
> "missing operator," generated by the string **2 3** 
>   
> "missing operand," generated by the string **(2+)**

The simplest solution that I was able to come up with is to do the following:

```
half_exp : exp '+' { $$ = $1; }
         | exp '-' { $$ = $1; }
         | exp '*' { $$ = $1; }
         ;


factor : NUMBER { $$ = $1; }
       | '(' exp '\n' { yyerror("missing right parenthesis"); }
       |  exp ')' { yyerror("missing left parenthesis"); }
       | '(' exp '\n' { yyerror("missing left parenthesis"); }
       | '(' exp ')' { $$ = $2; }
       | '(' half_exp ')' { yyerror("missing operand"); exit(0); }
       ;

exp : exp '+' term { $$ = $1 + $3; }
    | exp '-' term { $$ = $1 - $3; }
    | term { $$ = $1; }
    | exp exp { yyerror("missing operator"); }
    ;
```

These changes work, however they lead to a lot of conflicts.

Here is my question.

Is there a way to rewrite this grammar in such a way so that it wouldn't generate conflicts?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible:

```
command : exp { printf("%d\n", $1); }
        ; /* allows printing of the result */

exp:  exp '+' exp   {
                // code
    }
    | exp '-' exp  {
                // code
    }
    | exp '*' exp  {
                // code
    }
    | exp '/' exp  { 
                // code
            }
    |'(' exp ')' {
             // code
    }
```

Bison allows Ambiguous grammars.

I don't see how can you rewrite grammar to avoid conflicts. You just missed the point of terms, factors etc. You use these when you want *left recursion context free grammar*.

From this grammar:

```
E -> E+T
    |T
T -> T*F
    |F
F -> (E)
    |num
```

Once you free it from left recursion you would go to:

```
E -> TE'    { num , ( }
E' -> +TE'  { + }
    | eps   { ) , EOI }
T -> FT'    { ( , num }
T' -> *FT'  { * }
    |eps    { + , ) , EOI }
F -> (E)    { ( }
    |num    { num }
```

These sets alongside rules are showing what input character has to be in order to use that rule. Of course this is just example for simple arithmetic expressions for example 2*(3+4)*5+(3*3*3+4+5*6) etc.

If you want to learn more about this topic I suggest you to read about "left recursion context free grammar". There are some great books covering this topic and also covering how to get input sets.

But as I said above, all of this can be avoided because **Bison allows Ambiguous grammars.**

Comment: I was asking if there is a way to rewrite a grammar without conflicts. Can you give an example?

Comment: Did this solve your problem? If so, please accept my answer.

Comment: I'm familiar with left recursion and how to eliminate it. At least the simple cases. I'm not clear on what you mean by symbols in braces as well as what is meant by `EOI`, is it **E**nd **O**f **I**nput?

Comment: Yes EOI is end of input token. As for curly braces, they represent predictive parsing using FIRST and FOLLOW sets (Dragon book - section 4.4). If there is some new questions concerning this you might wanna open another topic.

Comment: But one more time, you can and should avoid all this because Bison allows Ambiguous grammars.